# How to return new list from another list?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a list of Ints:

```
// List<Int>
val listOfInts = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

and I want to transfort this into another `List<String>`, where it only has odd numbers like:

```
// List<String>
val listOfStrings = listOf("1", "3", "5", "7", "9")
```

Tried:

```
fun convertIntListToStringList(listOfInts: List<Int>): List<String> {
    return listOfInts.map{
        if (it.rem(2) == 0) it.toString()    
    }
}
```

Comment: Since u want odd it should be != 0

Comment: Another solution is use mapNotNull. ```listOfInts.mapNotNull{ if (it.rem(2) == 0) it.toString()  else null; }```

Comment: @Todd `mapNotNull` applies to the result of the lambda, not the input list. @JTejedor also: `mapNotNull{ it.takeIf { it % 2 == 0 } }`. But IMO it's best to avoid using nulls for flow if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:
`listOfInts.filter { it % 2 == 1 }.map { it.toString() }`

Comment: Yeah - also all the collection functions like ``map``, ``filter`` etc. produce new lists, except for the ones with ``to`` in their name (``mapTo``, ``filterTo`` etc.) which stick the results in a mutable collection you provide